# How to create android drawer menu in Adobe Flash?

Tags: flash, menu, touch, adobe, drawer

I need to build a prototype of an app, that showcases basic idea of navigation of an android app. So Adobe Flash and AIR.
Quickest thing that comes to mind is flash, since I already have the mockups done in photothop, and really have an idea how to glue it together in flash.

What worries me is the android-like drawer menu.

I know you need areas of event detection for touch events to be triggered.
So once you layer an object that detects "scrolling" gesture, on top of individual objects that detect taps for menu items, will it still work? Because I dont think you can stack touch detectors on top of eachother.

Any idea how to do this?

Basicly what I want to simulate is:
1. you open your drawer menu (just like in Gmail app for android, f.e.)
2. the menu slides over your content
3. you scroll it up and down, browsing the list of items in the menu list.
4. you tap one of them, which hides your menu and navigates you to a proper frame.

Im just worried how to design the layer that detects the "touch-move" event for scrolling and "tap" (which is basically a mouse event for AIR) for an individual list item in the menu.

So i got this mockup, I encase it as Movie Clip, give it a unique instance name and give it action script to detect touch-move, for scrolling.
but how to place the tap detecting objects for list items?

I hope I made it clear for you guys :) 
Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

.. You should take a look at this :

- [Using TweenLite](http://www.riacodes.com/flash/sliding-menu-with-actionscript-3-and-tweenlite/)
- [Using The TimeLine](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/slidingmenu/)